# Array.push(row) only pushing last row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I am attempting to import a csv file with papa parse and my processChunk function is only pushing the last row into the array. Any ideas?

somebody stole sweetrolls so I am typing more than I need too.
Here is the component below that holds the Importer.js

I used to be an adventurer like you then I took an arrow to the knee

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import { Importer, ImporterField } from "react-csv-importer";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Media } from "reactstrap";
import { CsvUploadContext } from "../../context/Context";
import { listFields } from "../../actions/index";
import { createCsv } from "../../actions/index";
import "react-csv-importer/dist/index.css";
import "../../assets/scss/theme/_csv-import.scss";

const CsvImporter = ({ register }) => {
  const { upload, setUpload, step, setStep } = useContext(CsvUploadContext);

  const fields = useSelector((state) => state.fields);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listFields());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Importer
        //chunkSize={100000} // optional, internal parsing chunk size in bytes -- this was causing error when too small
        assumeNoHeaders={false} // optional, keeps "data has headers" checkbox off by default
        restartable={false} // optional, lets user choose to upload another file when import is complete
        onStart={({ file, fields, columns, skipHeaders }) => {
          // optional, invoked when user has mapped columns and started import
          // prepMyAppForIncomingData();
          console.log("onStart ran");
        }}
        processChunk={async (rows, { startIndex }) => {
          // required, receives a list of parsed objects based on defined fields and user column mapping;
          // may be called several times if file is large
          // (if this callback returns a promise, the widget will wait for it before parsing more data)
          const array = [];
          for (let row of rows) {
            array.push(row);

            //  await myAppMethod(row);
          }
          setUpload({
            ...upload,
            contacts: array,
          }); // this is only saving the last row...
          console.log("processChunk ran");
        }}
        onComplete={({ file, preview, fields, columnFields }) => {
          dispatch(createCsv(upload));
          //upload has array of one contact
          // optional, invoked right after import is done (but user did not dismiss/reset the widget yet)
          // showMyAppToastNotification();
          console.log("onComplete ran");
        }}
        onClose={({ file, preview, fields, columnFields }) => {
          console.log("onClose ran");
          // optional, invoked when import is done and user clicked "Finish"
          // (if this is not specified, the widget lets the user upload another file)
          setStep(step + 1);
        }}
        // CSV options passed directly to PapaParse if specified:
        delimiter={","}
        skipEmptyLines={true}
      >
        <ImporterField name="first_name" label="First Name" />
        <ImporterField name="last_name" label="Last Name" />
        <ImporterField name="phone_number" label="Phone Number" />
        <ImporterField name="phone_type" label="Phone Type" />
        <ImporterField name="email" label="Email" optional />
      </Importer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CsvImporter;
```

Comment: i'm sorry.. your code is too poorly formatted, it makes it hard to figure out what's going on..

Comment: WIthout knowing how the Importer works, maybe you can try specify the chuckSize?

Comment: do a `console.log()` once array has been completely created by pushing rows. Then you can see all the rows are pushed not only last row. This isn't an issue relevant to `array.push()` method. Please provide more information on how you've created `CsvUploadContext` ?

Comment: export const CsvUploadContext = createContext({ upload: {} })

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you defined the array variable to const.

You can try to define it to let

````
        let array = []
        for (let row of rows) {
          array.push(row)

          //  await myAppMethod(row);
        }
    ```
````

Comment: array should be a const. pushing a value to it does not redefine it.  Only when using `array = ` again would you have to set it to a `let`

Comment: A tip when you write answers is to double check the claims you're unsure on by the inspect devtools console :)

Comment: `const` doesn't prevent pushing into an array https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp

Comment: Ive narrowed it down to having something to do with the delimiters in papa parse, I am still searching for the anwer I will post when I solve.